# Reading and processing histograms stored in ROOT files

Tags: python, python-2.x, file, data-visualization

## The Context

My daily workflow largely consists of producing, styling, and circulating plots from a dataset to my advisor and collaborators.  We use the C++ framework [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/) to generate and store histograms and I am writing my code in Python to take advantage of its Python bindings ([PyROOT](https://root.cern.ch/pyroot)).

Since a ROOT file is the fundamental unit of our datasets, I wrote a simple context manager to facilitate the common task of opening a ROOT file, retrieving some histograms, and then closing the file.

```
import ROOT

class HistogramFile(object):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def __enter__(self):
        self.file = ROOT.TFile.Open(self.filename, 'read')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        self.file.Close()

    def get_histogram(self, name):
        """Return the histogram identified by name from the file.
        """
        # The TFile::Get() method returns a pointer to an object stored in a ROOT file.
        hist = self.file.Get(name)
        if hist:
            return hist
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('Unable to retrieve histogram named {0} from {1}'.format(name, self.filename))
```

This allows me to write the following snippet (imports of necessary modules implied)

```
f = ROOT.TFile.Open('dataset.root', 'read')
# Setup a canvas for plotting. The arguments are a name, an optional title, and the width and height in pixels.
canvas = ROOT.TCanvas('canvas', '', 500, 500)
hist = f.Get('electron_momentum')
hist.Draw()
canvas.SaveAs('plot.pdf')
f.Close()
```

in a more idiomatic fashion

```
with HistogramFile('dataset.root') as f:
    canvas = ROOT.TCanvas('canvas', '', 500, 500)
    hist = f.get_histogram('electron_momentum')
    hist.Draw()
    canvas.SaveAs('plot.pdf')
```

A dataset is often a collection of multiple ROOT files, so to make a plot I need to sum the histograms with the same name from each of its files together. The following snippet does not work, and demonstrated to me that the files must remain open in order to access their histograms.

```
with HistogramFile('dataset_part1.root') as f:
    hist_1 = f.get_histogram('electron_momentum')

with HistogramFile('dataset_part2.root') as f:
    hist_2 = f.get_histogram('electron_momentum')

# The next line causes a " *** Break *** segmentation violation"
hist_total = hist_1 + hist_2
```

After some searching, I discovered contextlib2's ExitStack, which allows me to programmatically handle a dynamic number of ROOT files.

```
import contextlib2

class Dataset(object):

    def __init__(self, *filenames):
        self.filenames = filenames

    def __enter__(self):
        with contextlib2.ExitStack() as stack:
            self.files = [stack.enter_context(HistogramFile(fname) for fname in self.filenames]
            self.close = stack.pop_all().close
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        self.close()

    def get_histogram(self, name):
        """Return the sum of the histograms identified by name from all files.
        """
        return sum(f.get_histogram(name) for f in self.files)
```

I now have a context manager of context managers that allows me to work with multiple files in a similar manner as before.

```
# A list of files that could be the result of globbing or os.listdir
dataset_files = ['dataset_part1.root', 'dataset_part2.root', 'dataset_part3.root']
with Dataset(*dataset_files) as dataset:
    canvas = ROOT.TCanvas('canvas', '', 500, 500)
    hist = dataset.get_histogram('electron_momentum')
    hist.Draw()
    canvas.SaveAs('plot.pdf')
```

## The Issues

1. Are there problems with my code that I haven't addressed? Any subtleties or technicalities I have neglected?
2. I personally have not seen a context manager of context managers when perusing other people's code during my internet adventures. Is it suggestive of poor design choice? I mean, suppose I want to go one level higher in abstraction and design a new class which facilitates working with a collection of Dataset objects. How would I do that without making my code context managers all the way down?

Comment: Nice to see a good `ROOT` question here :)

Comment: I just used that class to make `with` open multiple files in parallel and extract the same tree from each of them: https://gist.github.com/graipher/9e8ad0776b6ab5a3935c4faf0f5fa091

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given both the documentation of [Python 3 contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack.pop_all) or [contextlib2](http://contextlib2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#contextlib2.ExitStack.pop_all), I’d say your usage is pretty standard for the tools at play.

However, there is something bothering me a bit in your code:

> ```
> def get_histogram(self, name):
>     """Return the histogram identified by name from the file.
>     """
>     # The TFile::Get() method returns a pointer to an object stored in a ROOT file.
>     hist = self.file.Get(name)
>     if hist:
>         return hist
>     else:
>         raise RuntimeError('Unable to retrieve histogram named {0} from {1}'.format(name, self.filename))
> ```

Why raise a generic purpose `RuntimeError`? If anyone wants to use your code and handle failures, they may catch more than it should.

As [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) says:

> Derive exceptions from `Exception` rather than `BaseException`. Direct inheritance from `BaseException` is reserved for exceptions where catching them is almost always the wrong thing to do.
>
> Design exception hierarchies based on the distinctions that code *catching* the exceptions is likely to need, rather than the locations where the exceptions are raised. Aim to answer the question "What went wrong?" programmatically, rather than only stating that "A problem occurred" (see [PEP 3151](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/) for an example of this lesson being learned for the builtin exception hierarchy)
>
> Class naming conventions apply here, although you should add the suffix "Error" to your exception classes if the exception is an error. Non-error exceptions that are used for non-local flow control or other forms of signaling need no special suffix.

So I’d rather write:

```
class HistogramNotFoundError(KeyError):
     pass


def get_histogram(self, name):
    hist = self.file.Get(name)
    if not hist:
        raise HistogramNotFoundError(name)
    return hist
```

The choice of `KeyError` as a base is a bit arbitrary, but I feel it fits nicely.

---

A last thing, if you intend to build a lot of canvas to draw on, you may also be interested in wrapping that in a context manager. Either by writing a class like you do (but checking the presence of an exception in the `__exit__` method before drawing) or by using the `@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator:

```
@contextmanager
def canvas(name, filename, idunno, width, height):
    canvas = ROOT.TCanvas(name, idunno, width, height)
    yield canvas
    canvas.SaveAs(filename)
```

I’m not using a `try: ... finally:` here to avoid generating a file if the canvas was not properly drawn.

Usage being:

```
dataset_files = ['dataset_part1.root', 'dataset_part2.root', 'dataset_part3.root']
with Dataset(*dataset_files) as dataset, canvas('canvas', 'plot.pdf', '', 500, 500):
    hist = dataset.get_histogram('electron_momentum')
    hist.Draw()
```